# Composite builds using directly github repo location

Tags: java, gradle, build, microservices

We have a microservice architecture and with number of dependent projects for each microservices. Lets say, in our case, we might have library in a separate repo and microservice in a separate repo. I was exploring on whether any possblities of mentioning the library as a includeBuild using the librarry github link. Something like below

//settings.gradle

includeBuild "github.com/myorg/utilibrepo"

Is this supported in gradle, instead of donwloading the dependcies as a gitsubmodules and then doing a inlcudebuild the above option will be straighforward (like import options in golang)

Thanks,
Mawy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like that with [source dependencies](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies). There are however limitations on this feature, so applicability will depend on your use case.